# How can I have Safari on OS X remember to permanently trust a website with my current location?

Tags: safari, macos, security, geolocation, privacy

The only options on the location privacy prompt are 'Allow' or 'Don't Allow', with a 'Remember my decision for one day' modifier checkbox as well. But what if there's a site that I trust in perpetuity? I want to give it permission to access my location forever. Why can't I do that?

*Safari 8.0 on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite*

Comment: I thought the "one day" was a limitation; and, if it is not checked, it behaves as you want (ie, you can either remember forever, or limit the remembering for one day)

Comment: It’s always been unclear to me whether it remembers for less or more than one day if I don’t tick “for one day”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if there's a site that I trust in perpetuity?

If you want to trust a site in perpetuity check "Prompt for each website one time only" in Settings>Privacy, visit the site, in the sheet that appears check the option "Remember my decision and don't ask me again" and click the <kbd>Allow</kbd> button:
[image]

If you get prompted to allow Safari to use your location, press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button:
[image]

Note that the Cookies and Website Data>Details section in Safari:
[image]

doesn't mention whether a specific site can access your location information:
[image]
so you might lose track of which sites you allowed.

For more information visit this article: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5403

Comment: Thank you for this. There must be a bug here because my 'ask only once' setting was checked, yet the dialog was prompting me with 'remember for one day.' I reset the setting and visited the website in question again and it was fixed.